# panda df: Subset frame by condition in 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to subset my df based on the condition of 2 columns:
Date and Person

**Condition:**
Date must be NON-BLANK except when Person =='Peter'

Tried the code but doesn't work, it removes ALL rows with blank in Date

```
df= df[ (df[df.columns[1]]!='peter') & (pd.isnull (df[df.columns[0]])!=True)]
```

**INPUT**

```
Date        |  Person  | 
            | tom      |
            | peter    |
            | jack     |
2010-10-4   | harry    |
2010-12-4   | sarah  |
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
Date        |  Person  | 
            | peter    |
2010-10-4   | harry    |
2010-12-4   | sarah  |
```

Comment: You "and" the conditions together. So there has to be *and* a non-null date, *and* a name that is not peter. tom and jack have null dates, so they will also be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `|` (boolean OR):

```
  # keep if peter               OR    if the data is NOT null
df[df[df.columns[1]].eq('peter') | ~df[df.columns[0]].isnull()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Chain condition by `|` for bitwise `OR` by columns names:

```
df = df[df['Person'].eq('peter') | df['Date'].notna()]
```

Or by positions - selected columns by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = df[df.iloc[:, 1].eq('peter') | df.iloc[:, 0].notna()]
print (df)
        Date Person
1        NaN  peter
3  2010-10-4  harry
4  2010-12-4  sarah
```